# How to change CSS styling from within Angular 2 Component

Tags: html, css, angular, menu

I am attempting to make a Vertical Menu with dropdowns. I have it working currently by using 'hover' in CSS but I want to make it so that a user can click a dropdown and the submenu will stay open even when a user is not hovering over it.

The problem I am running into is that, when I click the Statistics dropdown, it will actually make it into the method showStatMenu(), but the submenu will not actually open/become visible. Which makes me assume that the code within the showStatMenu() is wrong for Angular 2 to actually change the CSS.

*And yes I realize that showStatMenu() is not toggling open and closed, I just want it to open first and then worry about toggling it open and closed later

HTML

```
<div class="dashboard">
  <ul class="mainmenu">
    <li><a (click)="showStatMenu()">Statistics <span class="right"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></span></a>
      <ul class="submenu" id='stat'>
        <li *ngFor="let dashboard of dashboards"><a class="indent" *ngIf="dashboard.id == 1" (click)="gotoDetail(dashboard)">Team</a></li>
        <li *ngFor="let dashboard of dashboards"><a class="indent" *ngIf="dashboard.id == 2" (click)="gotoDetail(dashboard)">Player</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

TS

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Dashboard } from './dashboard';
import { DashboardService } from './dashboard.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-dashboard',
  templateUrl: 'dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ 'dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  // Took out init method and other irrelevant code

  showStatMenu(){
    document.getElementById('stat').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('stat').style.width = '200px';
  }
}
```

CSS (May be useful, but I don't think it is the problem)

```
html, body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navigation {
  width: 300px;
}

.mainmenu, .submenu {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 200px;
}

.mainmenu a {
  display: block;
  background-color: #d7dfea;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #000;
}

.mainmenu a:hover {
  background-color: #5a98fc;
  cursor: hand;
}

/*.mainmenu li:hover .submenu {
  display: block;
  max-height: 200px;
}*/ /*Hiding hover option*/

.submenu a {
  background-color: #9a9c9e;
  text-indent: 20px;
}

.submenu a:hover {
  background-color: #55d3ed;
  cursor: hand;
}

.submenu {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

.right{
  float: right;
}
```

Thanks for the help, this has been bugging me for way longer than it should!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to avoid direct DOM access from code in Angular2. Rather use bindings and directives like `ngStyle`:

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  showStat:boolean = false;
}
```

```
<div class="dashboard">
  <ul class="mainmenu">
    <li><a (click)="showStat = !showStat">Statistics <span class="right"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></span></a>
      <ul class="submenu" [ngStyle]="{'display': showStat ? 'block' : 'none, 'width': showStat ? '200px' : '0'}" >
        <li *ngFor="let dashboard of dashboards"><a class="indent" *ngIf="dashboard.id == 1" (click)="gotoDetail(dashboard)">Team</a></li>
        <li *ngFor="let dashboard of dashboards"><a class="indent" *ngIf="dashboard.id == 2" (click)="gotoDetail(dashboard)">Player</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you think it needs to be reloaded? I don't really understand the problem.

Comment: Thanks! This is working, there is one more thing I had to change to make it work. I needed to comment out the max-height line of code within my CSS file where it initializes .submenu, that was my fault for not recognizing it

Comment: Great. .  .  . .  . .