# Angular - mat-table : show or hide mat-cell content

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a simple mat-table, where the user accept or reject the row of the table

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="accept">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>accept </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
    <button (click)="accept(row)" mat-raised-button id="accept">accept</button>
  </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="reject">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>reject </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
    <button (click)="reject(row)" mat-raised-button id="reject">reject</button> </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

So, when the row is already accepted or rejected, those buttons should be hidden

I tried this

```
 document.getElementById("accept").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

and this

```
 document.getElementById("accept").style.display = 'none';
```

but they didn't work, I got an error "**Cannot read property 'style' of null**"

I don't know if the question is clear enough but if you need more information I will provide.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change CSS styling from within Angular 2 Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40295832/how-to-change-css-styling-from-within-angular-2-component)

Comment: cant you use attribute binding in this case in the corresponding button elements? LIke `<button [disabled]="someCondition" (click)="accept(row)" mat-raised-button id="accept">accept</button>`

Comment: @AshrafulIslam thank you I will try this

Comment: Please click on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48226868/document-getelementbyid-replacement-in-angular4-typescript/48226924) to find better way of using html elements.

Answer (score 0):

Where in typescript do you set the style? Most probably it should be in the `ngAfterViewInit` hook as the buttons are not in the DOM yet, if you are trying to set the style before it.

Comment: it is in a separated function getData() where I get data and show them on the table

Comment: If getData() is invoked before the view is compiled, the result will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You have some approaches for this:
1)  changing the html of the button to

```
<button #acceptButton (click)="accept(row,acceptButton)" mat-raised-button id="accept">accept</button>
```

then in your accept function you can access element native properties 
something like this:

```
accept(row,buttonRef){
    buttonRef._elementRef.nativeElement.style.display = 'none'
bla bla logic
}
```

this will change the button display property to none and hide the button

2) you can attach logic to *ngIf then the button will be removed from the DOM
 example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngif-else)

Answer (score 0):

Add to your div/container of your Tab:

```
[ngClass]="{ 'invisible': !displayTab}"

    .invisible * {
    visibility: hidden !important;
    transition: 0s !important;
}
```

```
    yourToggleFunction(): void{
     this.displayTab = !this.displayTab;
   }
```

Then you can switch it with a `(click)="yourToggleFunction()"`.

This might help:
[How to hide tab, but keep content of tab displayed in angular material in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48871755/how-to-hide-tab-but-keep-content-of-tab-displayed-in-angular-material-in-angula?rq=1)

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.